# Finding the difference between two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. Both of them have 2 columns with character values, but df1 has 2239 observations and df2 has 2240 observations. I want to find out what the extra observation is in df2.

I have tried `setdiff`, which returns me 0 observations. I have also tried `comparedf` in the arsenal package: it tells me there is one extra observation but does not tell me which one.

Does anyone know other functions I can use to find the answer? I apologize that I can't provide a minimum reproducible example, as I'm not even sure what the difference in these dataframes is.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `waldo::compare(df1, df2)`? e.g. `waldo::compare(mtcars, mtcars[c(1:19, 21:32),])`

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1)`

Comment: Thank you! They worked!